# Solving radical equations

Tags: radicals

How to solve the following equation without graphing it?
I have tried graphing it and got the answer y=121. It appears as a linear function, but I do not know why it gives a line.

The equations is as follows:
$$y+\sqrt{y}-132=0$$
How may I solve it without graphing it?

Comment: It is not a linear function. Please elaborate on your conjecture: "It appears as a linear function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is not linear; it is actually a quadratic in disguise.  You can solve it by setting $x = \sqrt{y}$.  Note that by the definition of square root, $x$ must be positive.  Then the equation becomes $x^2+x-132 = (x+12)(x-11) = 0$, so $x = -12$ or $11$.  Since $x$ is positive, $x = 11$, so $y = x^2 = 121$.